# Proving that $\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(3x^2-3)\sin(x) = 0$.

Tags: limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(3x^2-3)\sin(x) = 0$.

So, by the definition I have to prove that

$$
\exists\delta>0 \text{   such that}
$$
$$
0<|x+1|<\delta \longrightarrow |(3x^2-3)\sin(x)|<\epsilon
$$

What I did:
$$
|(3x^2-3)\sin(x)|=3|x+1||x-1||\sin(x)|\leq3|x+1||x-1|
$$

Let $\delta_1=1$ then:

$$
-1<x+1<1 \longrightarrow -3<x-1<-1<3 \longrightarrow |x-1|<3
$$

So:
$$
3|x+1||x-1||\sin(x)|\leq3|x+1||x-1|<3|x+1|\cdot3<\epsilon
$$

$$
|x+1|<\frac\epsilon9
$$

So I let $\delta=\min(1,\frac\epsilon9)$ and I'm done?

Did I screw up anywhere?

What are other ways to prove this?

Comment: Looks good as far as I can tell. You could add a bit of prose to the "so:" line explaining that you want the LHS to be $< \epsilon$ and didn't derive that it is. You then set $\delta$ correspondingly in the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, your proof is not complete. You've made it quite likely that $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac\epsilon 9\right\}$ will suffice, but it's not a formal proof yet.  To complete the formal proof, you have to show that this $\delta$ works for every $\epsilon>0$. This is quite tedious and routine, and it will be extremely similar to what you already did, however it must be done. Other than that the proof looks fine.

N.B. I would just like to note that the definition you wrote down, is missing something quite important. It should inculde at some point the phrase **for every $\epsilon>0$**. It's a petty comment, I know, but it realy is quite vital to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The basic result 
I use here is that,
if
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)
\ne 0$,
then
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x)
= 0$
if and only if
$\lim_{x \to a} g(x)
= 0$.

First of all,
$\sin(-1) 
\ne 0$,
so
$\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(3x^2-3)\sin(x)
 = 0$
if and only if
$\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(3x^2-3)
 = 0$.

Second,
$3x^2-3
=3(x^2-1)
=3(x+1)(x-1)
$,
and
$3((-1)-1)
=-6$,
so
$\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(3x^2-3)
 = 0$
if and only if
$\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(x+1)
 = 0$.

Finally,
you be able to prove that
$\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(x+1)
 = 0$.

Comment: Additionally, if $\; |f(x)|<M \;$ and $\; g(x)\rightarrow 0\;$then $f(x)*g(x)\rightarrow 0$